# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier never returns nil

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a custom UITableViewCell in my UITableView but the problem is that the cell is never nil when calling the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Why is this ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"PHResultTableViewCell" bundle: nil];
    [[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    PHResultTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        PackageHolidayItem *obj=[[PackageHolidayItem alloc]init];
        obj= [totalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.packageHolidayItem = obj;
        [cell loadRow];

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you using storyboards ?

Comment: Even if you did not register a nib and dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier could return nil, configuring the cell only in the `if (cell == nil) { ... }` case would be wrong.

Answer (score 22):

Starting in iOS 5 when you use storyboards and your reuse identifier matches a prototype in your storyboard you will not get a nil returned from dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier.

From Apple Doc:

> Table View Programming Guide for iOS
>
> > Creating and Configuring a Table View
> >
> > > Populating a Dynamic Table View with Data
> > >
> > > If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell
> > >       that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid
> > >       cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method
> > >       creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This
> > >       eliminates the need to check the return value for nil and create a
> > >       cell manually.

You can log the cell address to prove to your self they are being reused. But don't ship with the logging it will really slow up your table.

```
NSLog(@"Deque Cell %p", cell);
```

Better yet use breakpoint to log it.

[image]

```
$25 = 0x097f9850 <DDSImageSubtitleCheckedTableViewCell: 0x97f9850; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 22; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x97f9740>>
$26 = 0x0a6a4a00 <DDSImageSubtitleCheckedTableViewCell: 0xa6a4a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 66; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa6a4b50>>
$27 = 0x0a3ad250 <DDSImageSubtitleCheckedTableViewCell: 0xa3ad250; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 110; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3ad390>>
$28 = 0x0a3ae640 <DDSImageSubtitleCheckedTableViewCell: 0xa3ae640; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 176; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3ae780>>
$29 = 0x0972a370 <DDSImageSubtitleCheckedTableViewCell: 0x972a370; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 220; 320 44); hidden = YES; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x972a340>>
```

If you just want the addresses

[image]

```
0x097f9850
0x0a6a4a00
0x0a3ad250
0x0a3ae640
0x0972a370
```

Comment: The two breakpoint setup screenshots appear to be the same, but get different output. Were they supposed to have different content in the "Debugger Command" field?

Comment: @pix good eye. Thanks for catching the typo it should have been 'p cell' not 'po cell' p is primitive print where po is print object and calls [cell description]. I've hacked the image. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14):

It does not return nil because you have registered a nib for cell reuse (`[[self tableView] registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];`).

if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` can't find a cell in the tableviews reuse queue it will instantiate a new one from the nib you have specified.

Comment: Maybe, but he actually registered the nib in `viewDidLoad`, and registered nibs take precedence over prototype cells. And the nib can't be nil, otherwise he would have overwritten the cell prototype and the dequeue wouldn't return a cell. I guess internally the prototype cell is stored in the same way as the registered nib is. To conclude: the actual call to `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` causes dequeue to return a cell, but there could be a prototype cell as well. The only way to find out is to remove the `registerNib::` call. No offense, I'm done nitpicking :-)

Comment: While I appreciate the exhaustive response, when I glanced at the original code sample, I quite simply didn't notice his registering of the NIB (which is funny, because I cleaned up his source code). I was solely reacting to his question about `dequeue...` returning `nil`. As we know, this happens both when you register a NIB as well as when you use cell prototypes. But you're quite right, as he's registering a NIB in his code sample, that results in `dequeue...` never returning `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out if you have registerd a nib to reuse a tableViewCell you are guaranteed to get an instance of cell. If you want to set some value to the cell. You can try modifying your code like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        PHResultTableViewCell *cell = (PHResultTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" 
                                                                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];];

        cell.packageHolidayItem = totalArray[indexPath.row];;
        [cell loadRow];

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am using storyboards

Comment: @TrineHaalsMadsen Do verify if the cellIdentifier given in the storyboard is correct. And I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is supposed to return nil. Why do you want it to?

The method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns a Cell that is about to be displayed, so it's actually good that it is not null - that way you can modify it as needed.