# Looping through JSON array and inputting string into grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I am having trouble inputting my string "handle" into a group UITableView that I have;

```
  for(NSDictionary * dataDict in servers) {

     NSString * handle [dataDict objectForKey:@"handle"];

}
```

I'm totally confused on how I could utilize this for statement to dynamically create new cells with the handle.

The actual UITableView is on the main view controller and doesn't have any cells. How can I loop through the values and create the cells with labels?

Answer (score 1):

You've to overrite this datasource methods for your `UITableView`, don't forget to set datasource for the table. Just reload your data once you fill your server array, `[table reloadData];`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return servers.count; //will create cell based on your array count
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     if (cell == nil) 
     {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }

     //show handle stirng from server array
     cell.textlabel.text = [[server objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"handle"]; 

     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Im confused on where i hook the datasource of the tableview up to

Comment: [Watch this tutorial video to learn setting UITableView datasource and delegate.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eog-Y_Beww)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrData count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    mycustomcell *cell = (mycustomcell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"mycustomcell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog( @"NIB = %@",nib);
        NSLog( @"Cell = %@",cell);
    } 

    cell.lblName.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.lblId.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Id"];
    cell.lblGender.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Gender"];
    cell.lblAddress.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Address"];
    cell.lblPhone.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Phone"];
    cell.lblEmail.text = [[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Email"];

    NSLog(@"tbl %@",cell.lblName.text);


    return cell;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 200;
}
```

here mycustomcell is Custome cell not tableview's cell... I hope this works for you.. Create new custome cell with named mycustomecell with .h , .m and .xib..

Comment: You don't need anymore to check if the cell is nil and load a nib because the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier already does that :)!

Comment: Raphael is wrong: `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` still returns nil for uncached cells. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` will crate a new cell object for an uncached cell.

Comment: @Raphael Oliveira, I think you are wrong, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns `nil` if no object was found in the reusable-cell queue. Please see the documentation.

Comment: From the docs: "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered."

Comment: Yes, and : `If no cell is available for reuse and you did not register a class or nib file, this method returns nil.` So checking for `nil` return is not optional!

Comment: Well I registered that in StoryBoard (and of course you could also use the method - (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier) but after that there is no need to check if it is nil unless you really like defensive programming.

Comment: I do not check for nil and I do not have any problem. Feel free to put an if that will never have this code executed if you do the correct approach of registering a nib.

Comment: Having no problem yet doesn't mean it's a good practice, iOS is caching cells in a queue and then fetching them back when needed. It's all memory concerns, sometimes when the app is consuming a lot of memory (usually when parsing data, using GPS processing or doing a lot of networking stuff), your app controllers may release rooms in memory for urgent need. That's why you SHOULD always test `if (cell == nil)`.

Comment: No @Malloc it is not. Because even after a high memory consuming and a further release of cached cells, the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier WILL return a new instance for you. Again "This method dequeues an existing cell if one is available or creates a new one using the class or nib file you previously registered". So in case of no cached cells, this will return a new one because the nib registration is already done!

Comment: @Malloc I found another doc that should put an end in that discussion: "Populating a Dynamic Table View with Data

If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell that’s defined in a storyboard, the method always returns a valid cell. If there is not a recycled cell waiting to be reused, the method creates a new one using the information in the storyboard itself. This eliminates the need to check the return value for nil and create a cell manually."

Comment: @RaphaelOliveira: Your notes would be true if we assume using cells only prepared on a standalone `xib` or storyboards, but in case `UITableViewCell` is initialized and drawn programmatically, I think that check is important. All Apple sample apps consider that. here is an example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

Comment: But @MaulikKundaliya has a custom class and a nib. He is not drawing the cell programatically. And btw, this example if from 2010.

Comment: And even for a programatically created cell the best aproach is to use - (void)registerClass:(Class)cellClass forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier OR registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier.

Comment: Well, check on the internet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382068/dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-never-returns-nil

Comment: @MaulikKundaliya debug your code and check if the cell is always nil. I think it is because you probably are not registering it so you are not using the cached cells.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method below available on UITableViewDataSource protocol.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```