# Use different init-method for dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to use my own UITableViewCell class, so in the corresponding UITableViewController I write

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentitfier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell //cellIdentifier is initialized
    return cell
}
```

I want, however, to initialize my Cell as I have to pass arguments when it is created. The Apple docs say, that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier calls (if a cell has to be initialized) `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`.

If there is a cell to be reused, the method calls `prepareForReuse`.

Either way, I want to pass arguments to my cell **before** other methods are executed (i. e. at initialization and in prepareForReuse, respectively).

What is the appropriate way to do this and is there a way to use other initializers as defined in the class that derives from UITableViewCell (MyTableViewCell)?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what kind of things you need to pass to your cell. You can create your own init method, but I don't know of a way to intercept prepareForReuse (in a way that would allow you to pass something to it). If you need to customize cells for reuse, you should probably do it in the table view controller using tableViewWillDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Actually pretty simple: I am creating TableViews in the Cells, so I need to provide the section number as this information gets lost. I just thought it would be good practice to provide the relevant information at initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a custom `init` method, you (a) need to make sure you do not have a cell prototype defined (because if you do, it will call the initializer itself); and (b) your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` appropriately handles when a reused cell was not found and therefore you have to instantiate your own (with whatever parameters you want.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as MyTableViewCell?

    if cell == nil {
        cell = MyTableViewCell(param1: "foo", param2: "bar", reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

        // configure new cell here
    } else {
        // reconfigure reused cell here
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Personally, though, I wouldn't be inclined to go that route. I'd rather take advantage of the cell prototypes and the standard initialization routines, but then just override the properties (or call some configuration function) as necessary, e.g.:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell

    cell.property1 = "Foo"
    cell.property2 = "Bar"

    return cell
}
```

This way I can enjoy cell prototype, the automatic instantiation of my cell object class, the mapping of IBOutlets and IBActions, etc., but do whatever special configuration I need here in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't now that I am not supposed to have a prototype cell. As to the `if cell == nil ...` part: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16388242/4170176) it is stated that _If the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method asks for a cell ...._ Therefore I am wondering whether your first solution simply overrides the created cell and whether you should either use storyboard and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` or go entirely programatically with some other mechanism?

Comment: If you use prototype, you can't intercept instantiation (hence my first answer, as you seemed intent upon calling your own init method w parameters for some reason). I prefer the second alternative, where you use prototype like normal, let cell be instantiated for you, and merely modify it as you see fit.